# serialization of IList<object[]> XmlSerializer with Generic Lists

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I am getting some type `IList<object[]>` , what is the best way to serialize it to xml.
And then read it back to `IList<object[]>`.

I just not see any easy way to do so.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The XmlSerializer chokes on interfaces. So you could convert it to an array or a concrete `List<T>` before serializing. Also you should absolutely [specify known types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5aakyae.aspx) because this `object[]` will simply not work. The serializer must know in advance all types that you will be dealing with. This way it will emit type information into the resulting XML:

```
var data = list.ToArray();
var knownTypes = new[] { typeof(Foo), typeof(Bar) };
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType(), knownTypes);
serializer.Serialize(someStream, data);
```

Or if you don't wanna bother with all this and simply get some human readable persistence for your objects you could use Json:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = serializer.Serialize(list);
```

And if you don't care about human readability, a binary serializer should do just fine.